# что значит self.name в методе __init__?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class Person:

    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age


bob = Person('Bob', 43)
ivan = Person('Ivan', 22)
```

Знаю, что уже много раз была поднята эта тема, но я хочу задать немножко углубленный вопрос. Я понял, что из строки bob = Person('Bob', 43): bob передается в параметры __ init__ в self, Bob также в параметры __ init__ в name, 43 тоже в параметры __ init__ в age. А потом эти переменные идут в строчку self.name = name, а точнее в name и age аналогично. Попытался объяснить, может звучать неточно. Если я что-то не правильно понимаю, объясните поподробнее, пожалуйста. И желательно не ссылаться на что-то.

Меня интересует конкретно строчка self.name = name. А конкретнее self.name. Никак не могу понять что это значит. Я хотел написать мои предположения, что значит эта часть строки, но не могу их описать, так как они не совсем логичны.

Суть. Я бы хотел максимально подробно узнать про часть строки, а именно про self.name.

Желательно не ссылаться на статьи, но не возбраняется. Заранее спасибо за ответ на мой глупый вопрос.

Comment: Это означает, что объекты этого класса будут иметь члены name и age.

Comment: почему в той строчку нужно self, что значит self.name. я могу предположить, что self.name это переменная класса, которая не инициализирована, а мы этой переменной присваиваем значение в этой строчке ( bob = Person('Bob', 43) ). так?

Comment: Значение присваивается в строчке self.name = name, а в строчке bob = Person('Bob', 43) происходит неявный вызов метода __init__

Comment: И ещё кое-что хотел уточнить. self.name это переменная класса или name это какой-то метод self. self.name это что?

Comment: self.name - это переменная класса.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow *self.name - это переменная класса* - это не так. В классах Python  используются два вида переменных: переменные **класса** и переменные **экземпляра** класса. Переменные класса определяются на уровне класса и применяются ко всем объектам, созданным на его основе. Такая переменная, как правило, имеет одно и то же значение внутри всех объектов на основе этого класса (если только она не используется для инициализации переменной).  Переменная класса, определяемая вне метода, как правило, пишется под заголовком класса и перед методом конструктора и другими методами.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Переменные экземпляра класса имеют индивидуальное значение внутри того или иного экземпляра объекта. В отличие от переменных класса, объектные переменные определяются внутри метода. (https://www.8host.com/blog/peremennye-klassa-i-ekzemplyara-v-python-3/)